# curl -> Cloud Flare

Tags: php

Как получить контент сайта когда на него поставили защиту CloudFlare ?

Перестал работать код:

```
$url = 'https://xxx.com/'.$pag.'/';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: А как она выглядит, "защита CloudFlare"? Добавляется капча "кликните на изображения рек"? Возможно, вам как задающему вопрос это очевидно, но мне, как читающему вопрос -- совершенно непонятно. Предлагаю вам переформулировать вопрос и уточнить.

Comment: попробуйте задать хидер при подключению к сайту 
`Content-type: application/x-7z-compressed`

Comment: Защита ждёт 5 секунд далее загружает контент сайта.

Comment: Сейчас они убрали защиту как бы и всё работает как было.